# Conditional without event

Tags: jquery, css

This code works if I use a click, keyup... function. But how to make it work without keyup or click. I mean, how to change the line-height just when the page is loaded?

(Notice that the divs have different height and I already have a jQuery document ready function)

In fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/1/

```js
$(".note").keyup(function(){
 var noteHeight = $(this).height();
  
 if (noteHeight == 25) {
  $(this).css("line-height","25px");
 } else { 
  $(this).css("line-height","normal");
 }
});
```

```css
#wrap { 
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:420px;
}

.note {
 width:100%;
 min-height:25px; line-height:25px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 padding:0px 10px;
 text-align:left;
 outline:none;
 display:inline-block;
 background:whiteSmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap" >
 <div class="note" id="primer" contenteditable="true"> First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line, First line,  </div>
 <div class="note" contenteditable="true"> Second line </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not clear what are you expecting imho

Comment: I think you could have stopped at "I want it to center the text inside," then you only need to change your `.note` selector's `text-align: left;` to `text-align: center;` Otherwise, if there is more to this problem, you really need to clarify your intent.

Comment: Ok. I have simplified the question. See update

Comment: RE: "just when the page is loaded" - `$(document).ready(function() { //your code here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your code inside the `$(document).ready()` event, and use the `.each()` function to iterate through your elements.

In this way, your code will run when the document is ready and loaded, as you want.

As your element already have `line-height: 25px;` in your CSS, you can just change if necessary:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.note').each(function() {
        var noteHeight = $(this).height();

        if (noteHeight > 25)
            $(this).css("line-height", "normal");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/14/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Of course. But it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/3/ I think that the problem is that not all note height are the same

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you have multiple notes. See my update! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".note").trigger('keyup');
});
```

This is how to do it for your code, however, I would seperate your code so that the line-height function is a seperate function called changeLineHeight for example... then you can trigger it by keydown, keyup etc and also just run in within doc.ready with changeLineHeight().

e.g.

```
var changeLineHeight = function(){
    $(".notes").each(function(i,el){
        var noteHeight = $(this).height();
        if (noteHeight == 25) {
            $(this).css("line-height","25px");
        } else {    
            $(this).css("line-height","normal");
        }
    });
};
$(document).on('keyup keydown paste click', changeLineHeight)
.ready(function(){
    changeLineHeight();
});
```

Comment: $(".note").trigger('keyup'); seems a simple clever solution. But it does not seem to work. Am I missing anything? http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/11/

Comment: Here I tested the second option with the function. It does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/13/

Comment: @Nrc here is the first one fixed too. You called trigger before defining the event, but with jquery you can chain them http://jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/16/

Comment: This are very good options and work very well. What is (i, el} in the function?

Comment: @Nrc the each function returns to variables per itteration, i is integer and el is the element. so i goes 0,1,2,3,4,5, etc and $(elem) is the same as $(this)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were getting the height of the document instead of the element. Try this code in place of your document listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var primer=document.getElementById("primer");
    var noteHeight = primer.clientHeight;
    //alert(noteHeight);
    // Your note height might not always be == to 75 or 25.
    // Maybe use <= or >= to work with a wider range of values.
    if (noteHeight == 75) {
            $(primer).css("line-height","100px");
        } else {    
            $(primer).css("line-height","normal");
    }

});
```

Comment: This is not the point. I use jQuery  $(function() or $(document).ready(function() and it does not work. Please check the fiddle:jsfiddle.net/n32u4gnq/3

Comment: Inside your event listener `$(this).height()` returns a number much larger than 25, so your line height will always be set to normal. I think this is because "this" in the context of your listener is referring to the document instead of your element.

Comment: I updated my answer and it works in the fiddle, so take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in `$(document).ready()` and you are good to go, because DOM should be completely loaded before it's manipulation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".note").each(function(){
   var noteHeight = $(this).height();

    if (noteHeight == 25) {
        $(this).css("line-height","25px");
    } else {    
        $(this).css("line-height","normal");
    }
  });
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/n32u4gnq/9/)**